# How can I add column name to the first column of a data frame that is based on a matrix?

Tags: r, matrix, dataframe

How can I add column name to the first column of a data frame that is based on a matrix?

```
 web_page <- readLines("http://apiolaza.net/babel/")
   library(tm)
   SampCrps<- Corpus(VectorSource(web_page))
   corp <- tm_map(SampCrps, PlainTextDocument)
   dtm <-DocumentTermMatrix(oz)
   findFreqTerms(dtm,2) # words that apear at least 2 times
   dtmMatrix <- as.matrix(dtm) 
   wordsFreq <- colSums(dtmMatrix)
   wordsFreq <- sort(wordsFreq, decreasing=TRUE)
   head(wordsFreq,10)
library     one     the    book   books   whose another     can letters   first 
     23      19      16      13      13       9       8       8       8       7 

    wordsFreq<-as.data.frame(wordsFreq)
 wordsFreq<-as.data.frame(wordsFreq)
 head(wordsFreq)
        wordsFreq
library        23
one            19
the            16
book           13
books          13
whose           9
```

However when I tried to name the first column i got this error:

```
 colnames(wordsFreq)<-c("word", "count")
Error in `colnames<-`(`*tmp*`, value = c("word", "count")) : 
  'names' attribute [2] must be the same length as the vector [1]
```

How can I solve this issue and name the first column with the name that I want

Comment: Your output from `head()` indicates that the `wordsFreq` data frame has only one column, so you can't assign names for two columns since there is only one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

instead of `wordsFreq<-as.data.frame(wordsFreq)`

use

```
wordsFreq <-  as.data.frame(wordsFreq)
wordsFreq <- data.frame(word = rownames(wordsFreq), count = wordsFreq, row.names = NULL)
```

Comment: Hello @cccmir , I got an error:"Error in data.frame(word = rownames(wordsFreq), count = wordsFreq, row.names = NULL) : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 0, 1240"

Comment: @mql4beginner i have updated the answer please try it should work

Comment: Thanks a lot @cccmir